# CSS Table Elements

Tags: css, html-table

I have inherited responsibility for some web page updates and have to work within the parameters of the existing design, but the coding used is all tables with lots of formatting in EVERY table cell. I am getting a headache just trying to work through it. I want to simplify by using styles, and need to have several different styles. Specifically, the table heading is all bold, centered and one font size, so it will get one style for the row. The first column needs to be bold and centered, and the fifth column is centered (but regular font weight). All the other columns are left aligned and regular weight. The rows are alternating between white and colored.

So my question is can I style the rows in two styles to change the color, and then how would I style the 2 columns that need to be bold and/or centered, or do I need to style each cell to make this work?

```
<tr style="height: 27.75pt">
        <td style="padding-right: 5.4pt; padding-left: 5.4pt; background: #d2eaf1; padding-bottom: 0in; border-left: #78c0d4 1pt solid; width: 41.4pt; border-top-color: #f0f0f0; padding-top: 0in; border-bottom: #78c0d4 1pt solid; height: 27.75pt; border-right-color: #f0f0f0" valign="top" width="55">
            <p align="center" style="margin: 0in 0in 0pt; line-height: normal; text-align: center">
                <strong><span style="font-size: 10pt; color: black; font-family: 'Tahoma','sans-serif'">2</span></strong></p>
        </td>
        <td style="padding-right: 5.4pt; padding-left: 5.4pt; border-left-color: #f0f0f0; background: #d2eaf1; padding-bottom: 0in; width: 137.8pt; border-top-color: #f0f0f0; padding-top: 0in; border-bottom: #78c0d4 1pt solid; height: 27.75pt; border-right-color: #f0f0f0" valign="top" width="184">
            <p style="margin: 0in 0in 0pt; line-height: normal">
                <span style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: 'Tahoma','sans-serif'">Grace Episcopal Church</span></p>
        </td>
        <td style="padding-right: 5.4pt; padding-left: 5.4pt; border-left-color: #f0f0f0; background: #d2eaf1; padding-bottom: 0in; width: 72.45pt; border-top-color: #f0f0f0; padding-top: 0in; border-bottom: #78c0d4 1pt solid; height: 27.75pt; border-right-color: #f0f0f0" valign="top" width="97">
            <p style="margin: 0in 0in 0pt; line-height: normal">
                <span style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: 'Tahoma','sans-serif'">Nyack</span></p>
        </td>
        <td style="padding-right: 5.4pt; padding-left: 5.4pt; border-left-color: #f0f0f0; background: #d2eaf1; padding-bottom: 0in; width: 96.85pt; border-top-color: #f0f0f0; padding-top: 0in; border-bottom: #78c0d4 1pt solid; height: 27.75pt; border-right-color: #f0f0f0" valign="top" width="129">
            <p style="margin: 0in 0in 0pt; line-height: normal">
                <span style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: 'Tahoma','sans-serif'">John Smith</span></p>
            <p style="margin: 0in 0in 0pt; line-height: normal">
                <span style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: 'Tahoma','sans-serif'">Tom Jones&nbsp;</span></p>
        </td>
        <td style="padding-right: 5.4pt; padding-left: 5.4pt; border-left-color: #f0f0f0; background: #d2eaf1; padding-bottom: 0in; width: 63pt; border-top-color: #f0f0f0; padding-top: 0in; border-bottom: #78c0d4 1pt solid; height: 27.75pt; border-right-color: #f0f0f0" valign="top" width="84">
            <p align="center" style="margin: 0in 0in 0pt; line-height: normal; text-align: center">
                <span style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: 'Tahoma','sans-serif'">222-1234</span></p>
            <p align="center" style="margin: 0in 0in 0pt; line-height: normal; text-align: center">
                <span style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: 'Tahoma','sans-serif'">333-6789</span></p>
        </td>
        <td style="border-right: #78c0d4 1pt solid; padding-right: 5.4pt; padding-left: 5.4pt; border-left-color: #f0f0f0; background: #d2eaf1; padding-bottom: 0in; width: 147.4pt; border-top-color: #f0f0f0; padding-top: 0in; border-bottom: #78c0d4 1pt solid; height: 27.75pt" valign="top" width="197">
            <p style="margin: 0in 0in 0pt; line-height: normal">
                <a href="mailto:johnsmith@optonline.net"><span style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: 'Tahoma','sans-serif'">johnsmith@optonline.net</span></a></p>
            <p style="margin: 0in 0in 0pt; line-height: normal">
                <a href="mailto:tomjones@att.net"><u><span style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: 'Tahoma','sans-serif'">tomjones@att.net&nbsp;</span></u></a></p>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

I have cleaned up most of the code with internal style sheet, but have two remaining issues. The width of each column does not change using width style in each column class. Also, when I change the font size from 11pt to 12 pt it wraps text in two columns and thus throws off the intended design of the table. I'm sure I am missing a fairly easy tweak at this point.

If it matters, I am using a site that has its own wysiwyg front end and I have limited access to source code - I can make some changes but not full control, but this is what I am stuck working with.

```
<style type="text/css">
.tablestyle {
border: #78c0d4 1pt solid;
cellpadding:none;
cellspacing: none;
border: medium none; 
border-collapse: collapse;
width: 740;
    table-layout: fixed;
}

#heading {
text-align:center;
line-height:normal;
font-size:26px;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
color:#252525;
}

.tablerowblue {
border: #78c0d4 1pt solid; 
background: #d2eaf1; 
border-right-color: #f0f0f0; 
vertical-align:top;
line-height: normal; 
font-size: 12px; 
color: black; 
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.tablerowwhite {
border: #78c0d4 1pt solid; 
background: #ffffff; 
vertical-align:top;
line-height: normal; 
font-size: 12px; 
color: black; 
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.tableheadbold {
padding: 0 5px; 
border: #78c0d4 1pt solid; 
background: #4bacc6; 
border-right-color: #f0f0f0; 
vertical-align:top;
text-align: center;
font-size: 12px; 
color: black; 
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-weight:bold;
}

.col1 {
width: 40;
font-weight:bold;
text-align:center;
border: #78c0d4 1pt solid;
}
.col2 {
width:80;
border: #78c0d4 1pt solid;
padding: 0px 5px;
}
.col3 {
width:70;
border: #78c0d4 1pt solid;
padding: 0px 5px;
}
.col4 {
width:170;
border: #78c0d4 1pt solid;
padding: 0px 5px;
}
.col5 {
width:140;
text-align:center;
border: #78c0d4 1pt solid;
padding: 0px 5px;
}
.col6 {
width:190;
color:black;
border: #78c0d4 1pt solid;
padding: 0px 5px;
}
</style>

<div>
&nbsp;</div>
<p id="heading">
Troops</p>
<p>
&nbsp;</p>
<table class="tablestyle">
<tbody>
    <tr class="tableheadbold">
        <td>
            Troop</td>
        <td>
            Chartered Organization<br />
            Meeting Location</td>
        <td>
            Town/City</td>
        <td>
            Unit Leader<br />
            Comm. Chair</td>
        <td>
            Phone</td>
        <td>
            E-Mail</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tablerowwhite">
        <td class="col1">
            2</td>
        <td class="col2">
            Grace Episcopal Church</td>
        <td class="col3">
            Nyack</td>
        <td class="col4">
            Leader Name 1<br />
            Leader Name 2</td>
        <td class="col5">
            222-1234<br />
            333-6789</td>
        <td class="col6">
        <a  href="mailto:johnsmith@optonline.net">johnsmith@optonline.net</a><br />
            <a href="mailto:tomjones.net">tomjones.net</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tablerowblue">
        <td class="col1">
            10</td>
        <td class="col2">
            Atonement Lutheran Church</td>
        <td class="col3">
            Stony Point</td>
        <td class="col4">
            Leader Name 1<br />
            Leader Name 2</td>
        <td class="col5">
            222-1234<br />
            333-6789</td>
        <td class="col6">
        <a href="mailto:johnsmith@optonline.net">johnsmith@optonline.net</a><br />
            <a href="mailto:tomjones.net">tomjones.net</a></td>
    </tr>


</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: What browser(s) are you making this compatible with? (If you're going for major browsers and IE9, you can use [`:nth-of-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/:nth-of-type) for some of this.)

Comment: What does the existing code look like? If there is HTML code for formatting inside each cell, then overriding it in CSS isn’t as simple as overriding or changing existing CSS. What does the existing CSS look like? And are you doing this just to “clean things up” (which usually causes them to be messed up), or is there are plan to change the formatting, not just the code?

Comment: @Jukka, there have been attempts to make changes to content, but the code is so convoluted it usually messes up the look of the tables. Everything is thrown together with lots of span styles and inline styles - see a sample of the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use class selectors..

```
.tableStyle td {
  text-align:left;
}

.row_w td {
  background-color:#fff;
}

.row_c td {
  background-color:#ffc;
}

.col_1 {
  font-weight:bold;
  text-align:center;
}

.col_5 {
  text-align:center;
}

.row_h { /*anytime you want to customize */ }
```

HTML

```
<table class="tableStyle" >
  <tr class="row_h" ><th ></th>.. <th></td></tr>
  <tr class="row_w" ><td class="col_1" ></td>.. <td class="col_5" ></td>... </tr>
  <tr class="row_c" ><td class="col_1" ></td>.. <td class="col_5" ></td>... </tr>
</table>
```

The rest of TDs/THs will follow the style instructed by the TR class style.

Comment: Using this method, I need to assign a class to every <td> element in my code, correct? Is there a way to assign the class to just the <th> element and have all the cells in that column have that styling? Is there a hierarchy between <th>, <tr>, <td> as to which code will take precedence over the other?

Comment: Having a CLASS for TR.. this will effect all its TH or TR..
Having said that, there is no need to add style for you TH since it is within the TR having row_h class.

In any case you want to specify style for TH..
You can make use of the following.

TH { /*style here*/ }

or with hierarchy selector..

.row_h TH { /*only affects TH inside a TR with class .row_h*/ }

Comment: You are using CSS as inline-style.. Try creating a stylesheet. Same result but way way better coding.. to clean it all up. Refer to this simple examples.. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Comment: Actually, I am not using inline styles. The person who set this up did. I am cleaning it up and at the very least using internal style sheet.

Comment: thanks - your code was closest to what I needed, with a few additions as noted below.

Answer (score 0):

You can target a specific td by using the `nth-child` pseudo selector, that way you won't have to go through all the tds and add a class to them one by one.

A quick demo here : http://jsfiddle.net/Ftb6x/

Not every browser supports it unfortunately : http://caniuse.com/#search=nth-child

Answer (score 0):

The markup looks like it was produced with Microsoft Word. It is difficult to override all the presentational mess there, especially the cell widths set in points, or fractions of points. I would suggest cleaning up the markup. I have a small [utility](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/cleanword.html) for that. It does not remove the pointless `p` markup inside cells, but that markup can be effectively ignored in rendering by setting

```
th p, td p { margin: 0; }
```

With the cleaned up document, set the font on the page (Arial is boring but better than Tahoma), then table borders, cell spacing, and cell padding reasonably.

Then put the heading cells (I suppose this is what “the table heading” refers to) in a `tr` that is inside `thead`, and use `th` for the cells. They will then be by default bold and centered. They should normally have the same size as the rest of the table, but if desired, make it bigger this way:

```
thead th { font-size: 110%; }
```

You might consider making the first column cells `th`, since they sound like headings, but maybe it is sufficient to set just

```
td:first-child { text-align: center; font-weight: bold; }
```

though such styling looks odd for data like in the code snippet – it looks like something that should be left-aligned. Similarly, phone numbers should hardly be centered, but if you insist, this can be done in this case by setting

```
td:nth-child(5) { text-align: center; }
```

To set alternating background colors, as in the code snippet posted, use

```
tr:nth-child(odd) { background: #d2eaf1; }
```

If someone pays you for extra work needed to make the styling work even on old versions of IE (IE 8 and older), then you can either add column-based styling using `col` elements or, perhaps better, use the [Selectivzr](http://selectivizr.com/) polyfill.

Comment: I know this is silly, but does CSS2 or CSS3 still use just style type="text/css"? Can you mix CSS2 or 3 in the same sheet as CSS1?

Comment: @dmwesq, yes, the media type is the same (and the `type` attribute is really not needed, it’s just the formality). In implementations, there’s just CSS, as something that a browser supports, typically covering these days almost all of CSS 2 and a varying amount of things called CSS3. So there is not problem in mixing them. The problems are in browser support to constructs.

Comment: I'm still working on this - each time I make a cell a th it loses the formatting of the tr. Shouldn't the th inside the tr that is inside thead retain the formatting of the tr?

Comment: Still looking for a way to control the width of the table cells without having to add a class to each individual <td>. I have the code down to as bare bones as I think it can be, and the only problem is the cells are not expanding to fit the content of each one to fit a single line, which is the effect I need and can be accomplished by addressing each <td> but that seems quite cumbersome.

Comment: Finally have it working - needed to add a colgroup and col width tags in the html - but now table is working perfectly. Thanks to all.